# Can't add to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

This is getting silly and driving me crackers.

I have a small test view controller where I loop through ten questions.  The answer get checked and the score goes up or stays the same. This happens in a -(void) checkAnswer.  No problem!

Now comes my headache.
I have a NSMutableArray declared and @property in .h
It's @synthesize in .m

But when I try to add "right' or "wrong" to it in checkAnswer, nothing get added.

```
 [scoreArray addObject:@"wrong"];
 NSLog(@"scoreArray checkAnswer: %@",scoreArray);
```

There is no warnings or errors, just getting (null) from the NSLog.

Tried with no joy.

```
  [self.scoreArray addObject:@"wrong"];
```

Anyone out there that could help me? I'm sure it's something simple I can't see.
Thanks

Comment: How do I do tat, and what is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you initialized array correctly?

```
scoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: I have declared in .hand synthesized in .m but not init anywhere. Not sure where to do it.  Tried in the init of the view, but it didn't help.

Comment: You can do this in viewDidLoad method, or anywhere else in .m file, but you have to do this before you add object. As any other object NSMutableArray needs to be properly initialized before using.

Comment: If I put it in viewDidLoad it tells me that I will hide the instance and I can't add anything to it in -(void)checkAnswer as it's outside the viewDidLoad scope. -I think...

Comment: Have you written this code exactly like I did? If true, post some code because there must be a simple mistake.

Comment: @Baretk. Tried it inviewDidLoad and it worked a bit better. Unfortunately I call viewDidLoad to load up the new question and display it and the array get erased. Any other place where I could put the init that would make sense?

Comment: Hey! I put it in the initWithNibName and it worked a treat! Thanks a million.